# Pandas - Apply a function on a comma-separated column of feature names and store the weights in separate corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe `df` in which the `feature` column is string of comma separated feature names in a dataset (`df` can be potentially large).

```
index    features
1        'f1'  
2        'f1, f2'
3        'f1, f2, f3'
```

I also have a function `get_weights` that accepts a comma-separated string of feature names and calculates and returns a list that contains a weight for each given weight. The implementation details are not important and for the sake of simplicity, let's consider that the function returns equal weights for each feature:

```
import numpy as np
def get_weights(features):
   features = features.split(', ')
   return np.ones(len(features)) / len(features)
```

Using pandas, how can I apply the `get_weights` on `df` and have the results in a new dataframe as below:

```
index   f1     f2    f3 
1       1      0      0
2       0.5    0.5    0
3       0.33   0.33   0.33
```

That is, in the resulting dataframe, the features in `df.features` are turned into columns that contain the weight for that feature per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Consindering that the goal is to apply the function to the dataframe features, one can use [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) as follows

```
df = df['features'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_weights(x)))

[Out]:

          0         1         2
0  1.000000       NaN       NaN
1  0.500000  0.500000       NaN
2  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

However, in order to obtain the desired output, there are still a few things one has to do.

First, adjust the previous operation to fill the `NaN` with `0`

```
df = df['features'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_weights(x))).fillna(0)

[Out]:

          0         1         2
0  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
2  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Second, one wants the name of the columns to be, respectively, `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`. For that, one can do the following

```
df = df['features'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_weights(x))).fillna(0).rename(columns={0: 'f1', 1: 'f2', 2: 'f3'})

[Out]:

         f1        f2        f3
0  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
2  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Now, starting from this previous operation, as it is missing the column `index` starting at `1`, one can simply do the following

```
df['index'] = df.index + 1

[Out]:

   index        f1        f2        f3
0      1  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1      2  0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
2      3  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Finally, if the goal is to make the index column the index of the dataframe, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) as follows

```
df = df.set_index('index')

[Out]:

             f1        f2        f3
index                              
1      1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2      0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
3      0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

---

**Option 2**

If one doesn't want to use `.apply()` (as per the first Note below), another option, and a one-liner that satisfies all the requirements, would be to create a new dataframe as follows

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame([get_weights(x) for x in df['features']]).fillna(0).rename(columns={0: 'f1', 1: 'f2', 2: 'f3'}).set_index(pd.Series(range(1, len(df)+1), name='index'))

[Out]:

             f1        f2        f3
index                              
1      1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2      0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
3      0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

---

**Notes:**

- There are strong opinions on using `.apply()`. Would recommend reading this: [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869)

Comment: @GonçaloPeres Thanks for the help. Considering that `apply` can be slow, is there any alternative?

Comment: @MxNx check the option 2 that I just added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame([get_weights(s) for s in df['features']], index=df.index)
         .fillna(0).rename(columns=lambda x: f'f{x+1}')
       )
out = df.drop(columns='features').join(df2)
```

output:

```
   index        f1        f2        f3
0      1  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1      2  0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
2      3  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the function get_dummies from pandas you can do:

```
# 0- Let's define an example pandas DataFrame:

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "features": ["f1", "f1, f2", "f1, f2, f3", "f1, f4"]
    }
)

# 1- Convert column of strings into Series of lists:

aux_series = df["features"].str.split(", ")

# 2- Use get_dummies function, transpose the result and fill NaN's

aux_df = pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(aux_series[i]).sum() for i in df.index], axis=1).T.fillna(0)

# 3- Get the 'weight' of each value diving by its row summatory

output_df = aux_df.div(aux_df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)

# 4- Print the result:

print(output_df)

[Out]:

         f1        f2        f3   f4
0  1.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0
1  0.500000  0.500000  0.000000  0.0
2  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.0
3  0.500000  0.000000  0.000000  0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "features": ["f1", "f1, f2", "f1, f2, f3"]
    }
)
df2=df1.features.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
df2.mul(df2.sum(1).rdiv(1).round(2),axis=0)
```

output:

```
    f2    f3    f1
0  0.00  0.00  1.00
1  0.50  0.00  0.50
2  0.33  0.33  0.33
```

Comment: Please double check your output. It does not match the desired output of the question.